# On what quantities entropy depends upon?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

[This](https://www.pdfdrive.com/an-introduction-to-the-kinetic-theory-of-gases-cambridge-science-classics-e156640807.html) book which was written by James explains a proof regarding entropy ($S$). It considers one case and derives the following formula,
$$\mathrm{dS}=\frac{N}{T}\mathrm{dE}+\frac{2NE}{3vT}\mathrm{dv}$$
He derives it from,
$$\mathrm{dQ}=p\mathrm{dv}+N\mathrm{dE}$$
Where $E$ is the avg kinetic energy and $v$ is the volume. Then he writes some partial differential equations basing on the fact that $S(E,v)$.

**My question:-**

Why is entropy a function of $v$ and $E$?

Answer (score 1):

The entropy (and any state function for that matter) can be seen as a function of many different sets of variables. You have the freedom of choosing a parametrization that suits your purpose. So the entropy can be a function of $U$ and $v$, or $T$ and $p$ or (almost) any other pair. This is an important point of thermodynamics (and a great strength). I also believe that this is a reason to view thermodynamics through the lens of differential geometry (the set of equilibrium states is a manifold and you can have many different parameterizations).

$S(U,V)$ is convenient from a statistical physics point of view because $U$ and $V$ are natural variables in the microcanonical ensemble and $S$ is a quantity that we calculate directly from the Boltzmann equation.

From a thermodynamic point of view, there is a very nice axiomatic approach to thermodynamics laid down in Callen's *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics*. There you postulate the existence of entropy as a function of $U$, $V$, $N$ $\ldots$.

Note that I use $U$ instead of $E$ which I think is a slightly better notation choice. It is not the same as avg. kinetic energy but average internal energy (i.e. it includes potential energy of interaction). I guess the confusion comes from the ideal gas where the two coincide since there are no interactions.

Comment: $U,V$ and $N$ are the most convenient variables for entropy even without the axiomatic approach by Callen. Only using these variables, the whole thermodynamic information about a system is encoded in the entropy function. However, this does not hamper to use of different variables. The OP expression uses $N,V,T$ as independent variables.

Comment: I agree with your first point.
The OP clearly uses $E$ and $v$ as independent variables.